# Face detection using opencv and qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am trying to implement a real time face detection program using opencv and qt.The code is
mainwindow.h

```
 #include <QMainWindow>
 #include <opencv/cv.h>
 #include <opencv/highgui.h>
 #include <QLabel>

 namespace Ui {
 class MainWindow;
 }

 class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
  {
   Q_OBJECT
   public:
 explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();
Ui::MainWindow* _ui;
CvCapture* _capture;
IplImage*       _img;
CvHaarClassifierCascade* _cascade;
CvMemStorage*   _storage;
QList<CvScalar>  _colors;
QPixmap*         _pixmap;
QTimer*          _timer;
QLabel* labelCapture;
private slots:
void on_actionCapture_triggered();
 };
//#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp

```
  #include <QtGui/QApplication>
  #include "mainwindow.h"

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   MainWindow w;
    w.show();

   return a.exec();
    }
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
    #include "opencv/cv.h"
    #include "opencv/highgui.h"
    #include "opencv/cvaux.h"
    #include <QTimer>
    #include <QLabel>

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  _ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
  {
_ui->setupUi(this);
QLabel* labelCapture;
_capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );
_cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad("haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");
_storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

_colors << cvScalar(0.0,0.0,255.0) << cvScalar(0.0,128.0,255.0)
        << cvScalar(0.0,255.0,255.0) << cvScalar(0.0,255.0,0.0)
        << cvScalar(255.0,128.0,0.0) << cvScalar(255.0,255.0,0.0)
        << cvScalar(255.0,0.0,0.0) << cvScalar(255.0,0.0,255.0);

  _timer = new QTimer(this);
  connect(_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(on_actionCapture_triggered()));
  _timer->start(10);
  labelCapture=new QLabel();
   }

  MainWindow::~MainWindow()
  {
cvReleaseImage(&_img);
cvReleaseCapture(&_capture);
delete _ui;
  }

   void MainWindow::on_actionCapture_triggered()
   {
// Query camera for next frame
_img = cvQueryFrame( _capture );

if (_img)
{
    // Detect objects
    cvClearMemStorage( _storage );

    CvSeq* objects = cvHaarDetectObjects(_img,
                                         _cascade,
                                         _storage,
                                         1.1,
                                         3,
                                         CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                                         cvSize( 100, 100 ));

    int n = (objects ? objects->total : 0);

    CvRect* r;
    // Loop through objects and draw boxes
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        r = ( CvRect* )cvGetSeqElem( objects, i );
        cvRectangle( _img,
                     cvPoint( r->x, r->y ),
                     cvPoint( r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height ),
                     _colors[i%8]
                    );
    }

    // Convert IplImage to QImage
    QImage image = QImage((const uchar *)_img->imageData,
                                         _img->width,
                                         _img->height,
                                         QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped();
    _pixmap = new QPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
     _ui->labelCapture->setPixmap(*_pixmap);
   }
   }
```

But iam getting the following error...
On function on_action_capture_triggered()
class ui::mainWindow has no member named ‘labelCapture’
pls help....

Comment: your namespace is Ui not ui. It is case sensitive

Comment: then the error becomes expected primary expression before token -> also i have declared _ui on MainWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not OpenCV question. You have misunderstood basics of Qt.

I recommend you to create new project with Qt Creator, and then, create your user interface using Qt Creators designer. So, if you'll done that, you'll have clean looking code with **private** `Ui::MainWindow *ui`, and then, using Qt Creators designer, create your actions and code them.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

if you have A QLABEL on your form then rename it to 'labelCapture' if not then you have to create one with the same name or you can change your code to the name of your qlabel .
good luck!